# How can I enable overlay scrolling in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 15.10, 16.04, scrollbar

Ubuntu's overlay scrollbar was removed in Ubuntu 15.10. I have 16.04 LTS and I'm wondering if there is a way to get it back. Is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on **Unity Tweak Tool**

> System -> Scrolling -> and choose Overlay

or from **dconf editor**

> com->canonical->desktop->interface and choose auto overlay

to install unity tweak tool

> sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool

to install dconf editor

> sudo apt install dconf-editor

[reference](http://linuxg.net/how-to-easily-restore-the-classic-scroll-bar-disable-the-overlay-scroll-bar-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/)

if none of these solution fit it possible this [bug](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/overlay-scrollbar/+question/290411)

Comment: None of those worked. So I guess it is a bug.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Remember to file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Install the Unity Tweak Tool using `sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool`. Run the Unity Tweak Tool and go to System > Scrolling and choose "Overlay" in the "Scrollbars" section.